# Convert the html template into Django

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am currently learning django, and at the moment I want to convert this page https://colorlib.com/etc/lf/Login_v6/index.html into django. I have tried heaps of times, still can't make everything right. The Button textures, label animations and fonts are completely not working. Let me show you my work structure below.

My problem is about using css and js under static/vendor fold. Seems the way I used got a bit problem, I have also attached my code for invoking the css and js under vendor.

Thanks for any help.

MyFirstDjangoWeb

```
--project
        --setting.py
        --urls.py
        --wsgi.py
        --_init_.py
    --project_app
        --template
            --myHtml.html
        --migration
            --0001_initial.py
            --_init_.py
        --__init_.py
        --admin.py
        --apps.py
        --models.py
        --test.py
        --urls.py
        --views.py
    --static
        --css
        --images
        --js
        --vendor
    manage.py
```

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>QC-Tool</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
{% load static %} 
<!--===============================================================================================--> 
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="static/images/favicon.ico"/>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/fonts/iconic/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/vendor/animate/animate.css">
<!--===============================================================================================--> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/vendor/animsition/css/animsition.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================--> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/util.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/main.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
</head>
<body>
 <center>
 <div class="limiter">
  <div class="container-login100">
   <div class="wrap-login100 p-t-85 p-b-20">
    <form class="login100-form validate-form">
     
     <span class="login100-form-avatar">
      <img src="static/images/my_Logo.png" alt="AVATAR">
     </span>
     
     <span class="login100-form-title p-b-0">
      QC Tool
     </span>
     
     <form action="/msggate/" method="post">
      <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-t-85 m-b-35" data-validate = "Enter username">
      <input class="input100" type="text" name="username">
      <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Username"></span>
      </div>

     <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-50" data-validate="Enter password">
      <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass">
      <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Password"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
      <form action='actionUrl' method='GET'>
        <button class="login100-form-btn">
       Login
      </button>
      </form>
     </div>
     </form>
     
     
     <ul class="login-more p-t-190">
      <li class="m-b-8">
       <span class="txt1">
        Forgot
       </span>

       <a href="#" class="txt2">
        Username / Password?
       </a>
      </li>

      <li>
       <span class="txt1">
        More options?
       </span>

       <a href="#" class="txt2">
        Click here
       </a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
</center>
 {% load static %} 
 <div id="dropDownSelect1"></div>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <script src="static/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <script src="static/vendor/animsition/js/animsition.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <script src="static/vendor/bootstrap/js/popper.js"></script>
 <script src="static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <script src="static/vendor/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <script src="static/vendor/daterangepicker/moment.min.js"></script>
 <script src="static/vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <script src="static/vendor/countdowntime/countdowntime.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <script src="static/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: Hi, the things not working are button textures, label font and animations.

Comment: href="{%  static 'css/style.min.css' %}". and Have you done the static files settings?

Comment: Make sure you put {% load static %} in your template that's really forget prone thing

Comment: I am sorry I didn't, let me try it. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I have tried, it's still not working.... I will upload my code please have a look. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined static STATIC_URL in your setting.py? If not then do this in
**setting.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And store your static file in folder name static inside your app directory i.e. **project/project_app/static**

In your template myHtml.html , use the static template tag to build the URL like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">

<script src="{% static '/js/main.js' %}"></script>
```

Do this in every link and script.

Comment: I have tried your method, I got this error message: "Invalid block tag on line 10: 'static'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?"

Comment: have you added `{% load static  %}` in your template??

Comment: also you don't need to add `static/...`  in your path. edit your code and add the updated code